# HttpRequestMessage - Decoding 'parameter' - c# net40

Tags: httprequest, put

I am integrating with a third party API via a PUT request (required). However the URL is not what I consider standard.

https://standard.com/services/U2FsdGVkX18qfVhkTn7JsiXWA8q4vco7vpU%2BmeKqiXKafdKxfJqsq1ELGFOHIilpoR7VXqUcg89yXiabxjjfVXiRmVqGOffsKw%2BKLp5OU6%2FJZaTyn6BYxi%2F10ndtWFLG2KgxRmm%2BxtgTAopUi6m7wWTnSoAlL8qoS%2F3UbiippOw%3D.

Note that the reservation number isn't in the body nor as a parameter, its just a / then the number.

They have encoded the reservation number (requested via another API call). The issue is I'm using HttpRequestMessage, this decodes the %2F to /. Meaning it fails. I have tried double encoding the special characters but this isn't returning a consistent response, sometimes it fails other times it works (using different reservation numbers, only the %2F is double encoded). Is there a way to stop HttpRequestMessage decoding part of the URL?

I have tried encoding/decoding but it always gets stripped out here (unless double encoded:

```
var path = "https://standard.com/services/U2FsdGVkX18qfVhkTn7JsiXWA8q4vco7vpU%2BmeKqiXKafdKxfJqsq1ELGFOHIilpoR7VXqUcg89yXiabxjjfVXiRmVqGOffsKw%2BKLp5OU6%2FJZaTyn6BYxi%2F10ndtWFLG2KgxRmm%2BxtgTAopUi6m7wWTnSoAlL8qoS%2F3UbiippOw%3D";

var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.PUT, path);
var requestMessage = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, new Uri(path));
```

**Update:** This was a design decision made by Microsoft:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/511010/erroneous-uri-parsing-for-encoded-reserved-characters-according-to-rfc-3986

The solution from their point of view is to add a setting in the
web.config. But this is a class library and therefore used by more
than one project. I don't want to alter that unless I really have to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a design decision made by Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/511010/erroneous-uri-parsing-for-encoded-reserved-characters-according-to-rfc-3986