# HttpClient decoding my encoded URI causes request to fail

Tags: c#, .net, http, urlencode

`HttpClient` seems to not respect encoded strings.

```cs
var id = Uri.EscapeDataString("\"MyId\"");
var uri = new Uri($@"https://www.example.com/{id}").AbsoluteUri;
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
```

My `uri` object contains `https://www.example.com/%22MyId%22` which is correct.

Inspecting `req.RequestUri` shows the correct value for every property except for `LocalPath`, everything else seems to have the correct `%22` encoded quote.

I then send the request:

```cs
await httpClient.SendAsync(req)
```

and it makes a request to `https://www.example.com/"MyId"` (no longer encoded?) and the request fails.

`uri.UserEscaped` shows `false` after creating. I tried to escape the entire URI using `Uri.EscapeUriString`, but that function is deprecated and suggests using `Uri.EscapeDataString` for the query (which I'm already doing).

---

I followed the solution from the GitHub issue in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072156/httpclient-decodes-encoded-url), however it did not fix my issue (using `AbsoluteUri`).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651260/why-is-httprequestmessage-decoding-my-encoded-string) is incorrect as it is not just the `ToString()` method, the actual request includes the decoded values.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992693/httprequestmessage-decoding-parameter-c-sharp-net40) is just a dead link.

---

How can I actually send my request with the encoded `%22` quote values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that `Uri.EscapeDataString`, just include the `id` as-is in the `Uri`.

```
var id = "\"MyId\"";
var uri = new Uri($@"https://www.example.com/{id}").AbsoluteUri;
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
```

Fiddler shows below request was made.

```
POST https://www.example.com/%22MyId%22
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use them (namespace System.Web)

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("")
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("")
```

Comment: Using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` yields the same results, the request is still made with the decoded quotes.